# Plotly Scatter3d of pixels along RGB components

Tags: plot, plotly-python

I'm trying to 3d-plot the RGB components of all the pixels of an image with plotly (every pixel is a point in a 3d-space where the axes are R, G, and B) while **having each pixel being painted with its color**:

[image: Example plot]

I've used the following approach, which does work great with a small number of pixels:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

pyo.init_notebook_mode()

data = list()
# for each pixel
for pixel in image_to_plot:
    # add trace as follows:
    data.append(
        go.Scatter3d(
            # only one point
            x=[pixel[0]],
            y=[pixel[1]],
            z=[pixel[2]],
            # set its color
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(size=2, color='rgb('+', '.join(pixel.astype(str))+')'),
        )
    )

layout = dict(scene=dict(xaxis=dict(title='R'), yaxis=dict(title='G'), zaxis=dict(title='B')), showlegend=False)
pyo.iplot({'data': data, 'layout': layout}, filename='so_example')
```

where `image_to_plot` is a numpy array of pixels (shape `(1000, 3)`).

But the growing number of traces almost makes my browser crash with 1000 points and does not even render above that. ***Surely there's a better approach?***

My goal is to have this work with 100k to 1M points. For a reduced number of colors (like grouping the points into traces of the same color after K-Means clustering), this works perfectly fine.

I thought about doing this the other way round and plotting a trace per existing color to avoid multiple overlapping points in different traces but this leads to 16M (256^3) possible traces so probably not suitable either.

Answer (score 0):

The `marker` dictionary can take a list for its key `color` and apply it element-wise, so this is allowed:

```
# Instead of this in a for-loop:
x=[pixel[0]]
color='rgb('+', '.join(pixel.astype(str))+')'

# Do this:
x=image_to_plot[:, 0]
color=list(map(lambda e: 'rgb('+', '.join(e.astype(str))+')', image_to_plot))
```

Complete solution for variable `data`:

```
data = [
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=image_to_plot[:, 0],
        y=image_to_plot[:, 1],
        z=image_to_plot[:, 2],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=2,
            color=list(map(lambda e: 'rgb('+', '.join(e.astype(str))+')', image_to_plot)),
        ),
    )
]
```

This is way more beautiful and can show up to 500k points within a few seconds on my computer. Over this threshold, memory limits are reached.